# how to check xDocument is null or Empty in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to handle the empty file which does not contain any data 
after running below code it gives error like root element is missing.

How can I check `xDoc` is null or empty?

```
string path = @"E:\Test.xml";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375590/how-does-one-test-a-file-to-see-if-its-a-valid-xml-file-before-loading-it-with

Comment: path is already exist but file is empty , i can use try catch but need some other  method to check particular XDocument is null or empty

Comment: It didn't understand why the try catch block does not answer your problem, can you explain what the result you want?

Comment: i just want to avoid this error , for string we can simply check like string.IsNullOrEmpty()    why we cant able to check for any XmlDoxument or XDocument

Comment: @yashfale because this is not string...

Comment: Just set xDoc to null in the catch block, and then check that the doc is not null before you use it elsewhere in your code (if(xDoc != null)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XDocument.Load expects a valid XML file. Otherwise an exception will be thrown. You can either check, if the file exists or is empty before calling XDocument.Load , e.g. via

```
if (new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length > 0)
{
   ...
}
```

or you can catch the exception.

```
string path = @"E:\Test.xml";
try
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
} catch(Exception) {
   // some problem
}
```

If this code is put into a static function the code would be more readable.

```
 var xDoc = MyXDocument.Load(path);
 if (xDoc != null)
 { .... 
 }

public class MyXDocument {
    public static XDocument Load(string path) {
        try
        {
             XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
             return xDoc;
        } catch(Exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can handle like this but need some other method in which i can able check the XDocument is null or empty

Comment: @yashfale - can you elaborate more in your question, why these kind of checks do not match your requirements ? If it is a matter of style you can write a static helper method like MyXDocument.Load() that returns null, if some error happened during loading.

Comment: understood ! , we have to use try catch block. no other way to check null or empty for XDocument . Thanks.